# Python: How can the origin IP of an http request be determined

Tags: python-3.x, ip-address

I'm trying to do something similar like [ipify](http://www.ipify.org/), a simple public ip address api.
How can the ip address of a http request be determined with native python 3?

```
from werkzeug.wrappers import Request, Response


@Request.application
def application(request):
    return Response('Hello World!')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    from werkzeug.serving import run_simple
    run_simple('localhost', 4000, application)
```

How would I have to replace `return Response('Hello World!')` to make it return the ip of the requester?

Comment: It looks like you want us to write some code for you. While many users are willing to produce code for a coder in distress, they usually only help when the poster has already tried to solve the problem on their own. A good way to demonstrate this effort is to include the code you've written so far, example input (if there is any), the expected output, and the output you actually get (console output, stack traces, compiler errors - whatever is applicable). The more detail you provide, the more answers you are likely to receive.

Comment: I'm just clueless on how to determine the ip. A hint which module/function and a few lines of pseudo code would indeed help a lot. My googling wasn't succesful so far.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ok figured it out myself:

```
req_ip = request.remote_addr
return Response(req_ip)
```